# Split sentence by period followed by a capital letter

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I'm trying to find a regex that will split a piece of text into sentences at `.`/`?`/`!` that is followed by a space that is followed by a capital letter.

```
"Hello there, my friend. In other words, i.e. what's up, man."
```

should split to:

```
Hello there, my friend| In other words, i.e. what's up, man|
```

I can get it to split on `.`/`?`/`!`, but I have no luck getting the space and capital letter criteria.

What I came up with:

```
.split("/. \s[A-Z]/")
```

Comment: show us the regex you're using so far.

Comment: What regex have you wrote so far?

Comment: Note that acc. to your requirements, the final `.` should not be split on.

Comment: Are you trying to split sentences ? Because in that case you would want to keep the punctuation `[.?!]` intact.

Comment: Well, if we are to split real paragraphs into real sentences, we'd better use some library already available for it.

Answer (score 3):

> Split a piece of text into sentences based on the criteria that it is a ./?/! that is followed by a space that is followed by a capital letter.

You may use a regex based on a lookahead:

```
s = "Hello there, my friend. In other words, i.e. what's up, man."
puts s.split(/[!?.](?=\s+\p{Lu})/)
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/VjXAfc). In case you also need to split with the punctuation at the end of the string, use `/[!?.](?=(?:\s+\p{Lu})|\s*\z)/`.

**Details**:

- `[!?.]` - matches a `!`, `?` or `.` that is...
- `(?=\s+\p{Lu})` - (a positive lookahead) followed with 1+ whitespaces followed with 1 uppercase letter immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/lVgn404Vl4).

**NOTE**: If you need to split regular English text into sentences, you should consider using existing NLP solutions/libraries. See:

- [Pragmatic Segmenter](https://github.com/diasks2/pragmatic_segmenter)
- [srx-english](https://github.com/apohllo/srx-english/blob/master/lib/srx/english/sentence_splitter.rb)

The latter is based on regex, and can easily be extended with more regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from Wiktor's Answer you can also use lookarounds to find zero width and split on it.

**Regex:** `(?<=[.?!]\s)(?=[A-Z])` finds zero width preceded by either `[.?!]` and space and followed by an upper case letter.

```
s = "Hello there, my friend. In other words, i.e. what's up, man."
puts s.split(/(?<=[.?!]\s)(?=[A-Z])/)
```

**Output**

```
Hello there, my friend. 
In other words, i.e. what's up, man.
```

<kbd>**[Ruby Demo](http://ideone.com/p2c41D)**</kbd>

---

**Update:** Based on [Cary Swoveland's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924330/split-sentence-by-period-followed-by-a-capital-letter/43924420?noredirect=1#comment74887632_43924420).

> If the OP wanted to break the string into sentences I'd suggest `(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[A-Z])`, as it removes spaces between sentences and permits the number of such spaces to be greater than one

Comment: I would not use a lookbehind here since it is fixed width and it is hard to control the whitespace. However, the OP example and requirements do not match in 100% and it is not possible to provide the best possible answer right now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Agreed.

Comment: If the OP wanted to break the string into sentences I'd suggest `(?<=[.?!])\s+(?=[A-Z])`, as it removes spaces between sentences and permits the number of such spaces to be greater than one.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: That's legit. Will add it to my answer.